# Context sensitive language is context free

Tags: undecidability, context-sensitive

Problem of determining whether a context sensitive language is context free is undecidable.

How to prove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a similar way to the proof that it is undecidable whether the language of a context-free grammar is regular. A general statement of such undecidability properties is [Greibach's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem) observed by  Sheila Greibach in 1968.

> Let $C$ be a family of languages effectively closed under union and
>   concatenation with regular sets, and for which equality to $\Sigma^*$ is
>   undecidable (for sufficiently large $\Sigma$). Let $P$ be a proper subset of $C$,
>   which contains all regular languages, and is closed under single
>   letter quotient. Then membership of $P$ is undecidable for $C$.

So, we have to check whether the context-sensitive and context-free languages meet the criteria of Greibach for $C$ and $P$.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this. I was wondering can this be proven by contradiction, NP, pumping lemma.

Comment: Basically this uses contradiction. If your question would be decidable, then one could decide that $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ for a context-free grammar $G$, which contradicts the fact that we can't. It is a complete puzzle to me how NP or pumping lemma are related to this problem?